# 2012 MB GL450(w164) PDC not working and looking for PDC controller location

Tags: mercedes-benz

Thanks in advance.

Issue: Bought 2012 MB GL450 but PDC is not working(Lights on but no detection nor warning as toward to front or rear objects). The dealer said that both the front and rear bumper were repainted.

Troubleshoot:
1. After investigation, I did notice that there was a front PDC sensor module missing(bumper looks ok but behind sensor module was missing) and replaced it with a new one. But still not working.
2. Bought MB2 scanner that scans PDC and Airmatic, it showed rear right inner PDC sensor was not connected.
After pulled out and cleaned all(x4) PDC sensors and swapped the PDC sensors, the MB2 PDC scanned 3x of them are not connected error.
Since it didn't make sense that 3x PDC sensors are not connected, I reattached the cleaned sensors and bumper.

3. After fully connected and run for a few days and scanned with MB2, it showed the swapped rear right inner sensor again(exactly the same error code even after swapped PDC sensors).

Conclusion:
I need to find out where the PDC Controller module located so that I can re-secure the PDC sensors wire connectors. I think it should be under driver side rear seat but I only saw Siri and unknown controller that looked like optic for audio or something. I was tracing back to the PDC cables that ran from rear(driver side) to front but not sure where it ended.

If anyone knows where the heck is the PDC Controller module, please let me know. Thanks.

Albert